# How to use zero as prefix if value less than equals to 9

Tags: java, android

How to add **zero as prefix** if value **less than equals to 9**, i am using below way of achieving this:

```
            int countZero = 0;

            if(countVat <= 9)
            {
                countVat = countZero + countVat;
                Log.d("countVat:", String.valueOf(countVat));
            }
```

but this not works for me, still getting **single digit if countVat value less than equals to 9**.

Comment: Convert result inot String

Comment: countVat is int type of variable @Sharpedge

Comment: You are summing two int's. Convert them to String before summing.

Comment: int countZero = 0;

            if(countVat <= 9)
            {
                String str = "0" + countVat;
                Log.d("countVat :", str);
            }

Answer (score 3):

Use String.format

```
String.format("%02d", num);
```